# Find all rows with unique column, only the latest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Edit**: Purchases contains a column called `Date` too, of course. My bad.

I have a table, `Purchases`, with columns `CustomerId`, `PhoneNumber`, `Purchase`, `Price` and `Date`.

I want to move information about customers to a new table, `Customers`.
That contains `CustomerId` and `PhoneNumber`.

Rows with the same `CustomerId` can occurr multiple times in `Purchases`, and I only want the most recent row for each `CustomerId`, since that will contain the most recent `PhoneNumber` for that customer.

I read some stuff about `DISTINCT` but from what I understood that is used to find unique rows (right?).

I have tried some stuff with inner joins but since I am a beginner, I don´t feel like it would contribute much if I posted it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
;WITH MyCustomerRows As
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS CustomerIndex
          ,CustomerID
          ,PhoneNumber
    FROM Purchases
)
INSERT INTO NewCustomerTable(CustomerID,PhoneNumber)
SELECT CustomerID,PhoneNumber
FROM MyCustomerRows 
WHERE CustomerIndex =1 --this will pick just the first row, which is the newest...
```

Comment: @hellogoodnight, Are you able to adapt my query to your needs yourself? Otherwise you'd have to wait a little... Meeting...

Comment: Hmm, I guess, but I thought that maybe after my edit, there would be possible to write a more simple query. But Ill try to figure it out myself. Thank you.